# how to set array params in get request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I use http get in rails. There are array params in the request. How can I encode the params into the request?
My code is like the next:

```
uri = URI(url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params) if params
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
data = resp.body
```

When the params have an array, such as ids, the url will like `"http://url?ids=1&ids=2"`, but I want to the url like `"http://url?ids[]=1&ids[]=2"`.

Comment: `{:a => [1,2,3]}.to_query
 => "a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2&a%5B%5D=3"` wont work for you?

Comment: Nice, it is work. Thank you!